# Angular animation transform x based on other elements position

Tags: angular, css-animations, angular-animations

I have defined an angular animation like this

```
 trigger('sampleAnimation',[
  state('selected', style({
     transform: 'translateY(-90%) '
  })),
  state('normal', style({
  
    transform: 'translateY(*)'
  
  })),
  transition('normal <=> selected',animate(300))

])
```

]

Here in selected state, i want to translate the X part also , here i can give x position in pixel or percantage, but how can i move it to the center of the currently parent div of the element, the element can be on left or right side as its a stack of cards. How to calculate and set the translate X amount in angular animation ?

Comment: Did you find how to solve this?